Coproduct preserving autofunctors on set preserve initial object.
According to Borger's theorem the ultrafilter functor which we show by $Ult$ here is the terminal co-product preserving functor from $\bf Set$ to itself.
If the concept of ultrafilrer is defined for the empty set then we must have $Ult(\emptyset) = \emptyset$.
Now assume $F: \bf Set \rightarrow \bf Set$ is a coproduct preserving functor. Then there exists a natural transformation $\eta : F \rightarrow Ult$. Hence there exists a function $\eta_\emptyset : F(\emptyset) \rightarrow Ult(\emptyset) = \emptyset$. Which means $F(\emptyset) = \emptyset$. That is, if $F : \bf Set \rightarrow \bf Set$ is coproduct preserving then it also preserves the initial object, which to me doesn't sound right. Is the above proof right? Or am I making a mistake somewhere.

Can you give a reference for Borger's theorem? Presumably it should refer to finite coproduct preserving functors, since the ultrafilter functor does not preserve infinite coproducts.

R. Börger, Coproducts and Ultrafilters, JPAA 46 (1987) pp.35-47.

The initial object is the empty coproduct, so (by definition) it is preserved by every coproduct-preserving functor.
Ok, but maybe your definition of "coproduct-preserving functor" only requires that the functor $F$ preserves binary coproducts. In this case, we still get preservation of $\varnothing$.
For any set $X$, let $i_L\colon X\to X+\varnothing$ be the inclusion of $X$ into its coproduct with $\varnothing$. Then $i_L$ is an isomorphism. Since $F$ is coproduct-preserving, $F(i_L)\colon F(X)\to F(X)+F(\varnothing)$ is the inclusion of $F(X)$ into its coproduct with $F(\varnothing)$. Since the image of an isomorphism under a functor is an isomorphism, $F(i_L)$ is an isomorphism, in particular it is surjective. But then $F(\varnothing)$ is empty.

About the new paragraph. We can also use that codiagonal $\nabla : F(0) + F(0) \to F(0)$ is an isomorphism, hence $F(0)$ is empty.

@MartinBrandenburg Or that the two inclusions $F(0)\to F(0)+F(0)$ are equal, etc.

I think I misunderstood your answer. Are implying that since F(X)+F(0) is isomorphic to F(0) then F(0) is isomorphic to the empty set??? Have I understood this correctly? Because as far as I know this is not true. Consider the functor that sends everything to the set of natural numbers. Then F(X)+F(0) would be isomorphic to N+N which is isomorphic to N which is F(0).

@amirhomayounNejah No, that is not my argument. As you correctly note, the mere existence of a bijection $A\to A+B$ does not imply that $B$ is empty. But in this case, we have more: the standard inclusion map $A\to A+B$ is a bijection. And this implies $B$ is empty.

@AlexKruckman Thank you for your answer. It was very interesting. I enjoyed it very much.

@amirhomayounNejah If my answer settles your question, you can accept it by clicking the green check mark.
